# How to extract column value to compare with rlike in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rlike

I have the below code in spark 2.3 .It shows error since rlike can only evaluate a string but not a column field, So  I want to extract the value in corresponding col(unique_handle_regex) column as string

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2).select("*").where(col(unique_handle) rlike col(unique_handle_regex))
```

Comment: please post your sample table and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
val whereExpr = Seq("unique_handle","unique_handle_regex").mkString(" rlike ")
val df3 = df1.join(df2).select("*").where(whereExpr)
```

Comment: Hi Srinivas, thank you for your response.your solution works fine.You have hard-coded the column name in the query right is there any other solution without hard-coding it @Srinivas

Comment: Thanks .. is this solution not solved your issue ??.. if it solved please accept this answer ..